# Key HIT/press event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to take key press event, ut this is not on specific field, its on page/window.

Example:
While doing automation, on web page I have short-cut key suppose <kbd>M</kbd> (keyboard key). So how should I achieve this? If it can be achieved by inserting a JavaScript then how can I write it? I'm beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.:)
I wrote following in ruby-
keypress_script = "var e = $(document).keydown(function(e){                                                      if (e.keyCode ==77){
alert('M key pressed');                                                                            }
});"
page.execute_script(keypress_script)
sleep 5

Still needs to be modify I think.Because as we wrote if M get HIT then it will show M key pressed. But we have to press M further action will be automatically taken by web.I want to just HIT M key in automation.How this can be achieve?

Comment: I am not sure on your problem. Can you elaborate a little bit more... You have select box on page?

Comment: No,There is no box. I want to rake event on whole page.Simple Example- If you log in to gmail.after successfully loged in if you HIT M then INBOX will get open.That code is written on website(where to go or how to take action) We just have to press M with help of java script.Is it making sense to you now?

Comment: Make ajax call to page instead of alert which will load the desired stuff on page..

Comment: No problem you can use  [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function of jquery, but just to be clear if you want to load completely new page on "M" key then use `window.location = "http://www.google.com/"` instead

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can do this as follow.

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 77) { 
               alert( "M key pressed" );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes its acceptable  but can you once go through my new comment? I explain the issue there.We are just a step back from reach:(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<script>
  function keyEvent (e) {
    if (!e)
      e = window.event;
    if (e.which) {
      keycode = e.which;
    } else if (e.keyCode) {
      keycode = e.keyCode;
    }
    if(keycode == 77){
      alert('Hi!');
    }
  }
  document.onkeydown = keyEvent;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want it on the window I would add a `eventListener` function direct on the window object like this. You can google the keyCode if you want to change keyCode. This works with and without jQuery library :) [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sagHc/4/)

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch(e.which) {
        case 77:
            if (e.ctrlKey) { 
               alert( "M + ctrlKey is down" );
               // do some here
            }
            else {
                alert("M is down")
            }
        break;
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.:)
But I want to give M key press as a input to page.I wrote following in ruby-
keypress_script = "var e = $(document).keydown(function(e){                                                      if (e.keyCode == 77) { 
alert( 'M key pressed' );}
});"
page.execute_script(keypress_script)
sleep 5
Still needs to be modify I think.Because as we wrote if M get HIT then it will show Mkey pressed. But we have to press M further action will be automatically taken by web.I want to just HIT M key in automation.How this can be achieve?

Comment: I put the comment "// do some here" and there you can do whatever you want to do, a redirect or ajax request or whatever. I saw your comment above and to show inbox maby you can use toggleClass with jquery and on toggleClass you show the inbox or some like that.

Comment: Yes correct. But I do not want if then. I want to HIT M on page/window   as a input.so action will be taken.M is global short-cut.Is it making sense?

Comment: If I am not totaly missunderstanding you, this is what you need. M is global shortcut then you need a second key input together with M to actually do some actions. Anyways I edited the code above for it and I hope it helps :)